# Generic behavior of "polynomialish" models of $\mathsf{Q}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, model-theory, forcing, theories-of-arithmetic

*(This question was originally [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717258/generic-behavior-amongst-polynomialish-models-of-mathsfq) - with different notation, some more explicit arguments, and topology in place of forcing.)*

---

Suppose $\mathcal{R}=(R_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of commutative ordered rings such that $R_i$ is an sub-ordered ring of $R_{i+1}$ and $R_0=\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mathsf{Rob}_\mathcal{R}$ be the sub-ordered-*semi*-ring of $(\bigcup_{i\in\omega}R_i)[x]$ consisting of polynomials whose $x^i$ term has coefficient in $R_i$ and whose leading coefficient is nonnegative in the sense of $\bigcup_{i\in\omega}R_i$. This $\mathsf{Rob}_\mathcal{R}$ always satisfies [Robinson's $\mathsf{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic), although beyond this the theory of this model depends unsurprisingly on the sequence $\mathcal{R}$.

I'm interested in the "generic" behavior of such models, in the sense of the following forcing notion: conditions are finite sequences of countable commutative ordered semirings, each of which is a sub-ordered-semiring of the next and the first of which is $\mathbb{Z}$ *(and which live within $V_{\omega_{17}}$ to keep everything nice and set-sized)*. Conditions are ordered by extension, every sufficiently-generic filter $G$ determines a sequence $\mathcal{R}_G$ and consequently a nonstandard model $\mathsf{Rob}_{\mathcal{R}_G}$, and for simplicity say that a sentence $\varphi$ in the language of ordered semirings is *generically true* iff "$\mathsf{Rob}_{\mathcal{R}_G}\models\varphi$" is forced by the empty condition.

For example, "Every number is either even or odd" is neither generically true nor generically false (the issue being whether $2$ is invertible in $R_1$). On the other hand, the more complicated sentence "There is some $k$ such that for all $n>k$ there is some $m<k$ such that $n+m$ is even" is generically true. In general, many basic facts about modular arithmetic have "perturbed" versions a la the above which are generically true. I'm interested in unpacking this more. Suppose we have a sentence of the form $$\varphi\equiv\forall x_1,...,x_n\exists y_1,...,y_k\theta(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_k)$$ with $\theta$ quantifier-free. Define the *perturbed version* of $\varphi$, which I'll denote by "$\varphi^\circ$," as follows (using overline-notation for brevity):

$$\varphi^\circ:\equiv\exists u\forall \overline{x}\exists \overline{z}[(\bigwedge_{i\le n}\lfloor{x_i\over u}\rfloor\le z_i\le x_iu) \wedge \exists\overline{y}(\theta(\overline{z},\overline{y})).$$

The idea is that $\varphi^\circ$ doesn't require $\exists\overline{y}\theta$ to hold on a given tuple $\overline{x}$, but instead allows us to perturb the inputs ($\overline{x}$ to $\overline{z}$) by up to a fixed factor $u$.

My question is:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is an $\forall^*\exists^*$-sentence in the language of Robinson arithmetic and $\mathbb{N}\models\varphi$. Is $\varphi^\circ$ generically true?

Note that we could consider "perturbed versions" of higher-complexity sentences, but the particular question above becomes boring: "There is some $k$ such that for every $n$ there is some $m\in (\lfloor {n\over k}\rfloor, nk)$ such that $m$ is not even" is generically **false**.